# Terrafrom data source a localfile and retrieve some keys from the content as output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, datasource, local-files

I Have a local file (named as x.json)contain some json content. like

```
{
    "client": {
      "apiKey": "xyzabcpqr!23",
      "permissions": {},
      "firebaseSubdomain": "my-project-1"
    }
}
```

I am doing data sources on this file like,

```
data "local_file" "myfile" {
    filename = "x.json" #localfile
}
```

Now I want to extract the `apiKey` as terraform out and pass the output to some other resource.

```
output "apiKey" {
   value = data.local_file.myfile.content
}
```

But I don't find any option to get that.

I tried this one also, but it is throwing the error as

Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

```
output "apiKey" {
   value = data.local_file.myfile.content.client.apiKey
}
```

Comment: I got one solution but it is using bash and jQuery.
`cat x.json | jq .client.apiKey`

Comment: Your file with json is an invalid json to begin with. So its not clear what you are trying to actually do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help.

Instead of using local file then output, you can also pass your configuration as variable.

For each `Terraform` module, set the client configuration as variable, before to plan and apply :

```bash
export TF_VAR_client='{"apiKey": "xyzabcpqr!23","permissions": {},"firebaseSubdomain": "my-project-1"}'
```

or

```bash
terraform apply -var='apiKey={"apiKey": "xyzabcpqr!23","permissions": {},"firebaseSubdomain": "my-project-1"}'
```

Then in the `Terraform` code :

`variables.tf` file

```
variable "client" {
  description = "Client"
  type = "map"
}
```

`main.tf` file

```
resource "your_resource" "name" {
    apikey = var.client["apiKey"]

    ....
```

Comment: the x.json file is actually generated by a script and I can't put it in tfvars manually.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this:

```
data "local_file" "myfile" {
    filename = "x.json"
}
```

You can access the specific values by parsing as JSON (it's read as text).

```
output "apiKey" {
   value = jsondecode(data.local_file.myfile.content).apiKey
}
```

As a side note, given this is a sensitive file I'd recommend using `local_sensitive_file` instead. `local_file`